# Dependency is not satisfiable: libprotobuf8

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, dependencies, deb

I get the error while installing a package (.deb) :

`ratatouille_0.1.1-1_i386.deb` (156.8 KiB) from here:

https://launchpad.net/~keithw/+archive/ubuntu/ratatouille/+sourcepub/4418864/+listing-archive-extra

I tried installing libprotobuf-dev but it's already installed.

Answer (score 1):

The PPA you are linking has built packages only for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty).

If you are trying to install it on 15.04, the dependencies' versions probably do not match, so it cannot be installed.

You will most probably have to compile the program yourself by grabbing its source code and building (there is a link on the PPA page).

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Could you give some links ? The source code is in ratatouille_0.1.1.orig.tar.gz  right ? Also, could you give some input/links on how exacty this ppa thing and sudo apt works, how could I install a dummy software say which says "Hello" through sudo ? THanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hello! This would be a good start: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto